# How to join array to string with comma per 3 items in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, string

Let's say that I have an array.

```
string[] temp = { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j" };
```

I want to join them with comma per 3 items like below.

```
string[] temp2 = { "a,b,c", "d,e,f", "g,h,i", "j" };
```

I know I can use

```
string temp3 = string.Join(",", temp);
```

But this gives me the result as

```
"a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j"
```

Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One quick and easy way, grouping your items in chunks of three:

```
string[] temp = { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j" };

string[] temp2 = temp.Select((item, index) => new 
{
    Char = item,
    Index = index
})
.GroupBy(i => i.Index / 3, i => i.Char)
.Select(grp => string.Join(",", grp))
.ToArray();
```

*Updated to use the overload of [`.GroupBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534304.aspx) that allows you to specify an element selector since I think this is a cleaner way to do it. Incorporated from [@Jamiec's answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18253373/497356)*

What's going on here:

1. We're projecting each element of `temp` into a new element--an anonymous object with `Char` and `Index` properties.
2. We're then grouping the resulting Enumerable by the result of integer division between the index of the item and 3. With the second parameter to `.GroupBy`, we're specifying that we want each item in the group to be the `Char` property of the anonymous object.
3. Then, we're calling `.Select` to project the grouped elements again. This time our projection function needs to call `string.Join`, passing each group of strings to that method.
4. At this point we have an `IEnumerable<string>` that looks the way we want it to, so it's just a matter of calling `ToArray` to create an array from our Enumerable.

Comment: Love it. Clean, simple and easy to infer what the code is trying to achieve.

Answer (score 5):

You can combine a `Chunk` method ([credit to CaseyB](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6362642/781792)) with `string.Join`:

```
string[] temp2 = temp.Chunk(3).Select(x => string.Join(",", x)).ToArray();

/// <summary>
/// Break a list of items into chunks of a specific size
/// </summary>
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Chunk<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int chunksize)
{
    while (source.Any())
    {
        yield return source.Take(chunksize);
        source = source.Skip(chunksize);
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice chunking implementation!

Answer (score 4):

It can be done by chaining Linq statements together:

```
var grouped = temp.Select( (e,i) => new{ Index=i/3, Item=e})
              .GroupBy(x => x.Index, x=> x.Item)
              .Select( x => String.Join(",",x) );
```

Live example: http://rextester.com/AHZM76517

Answer (score 3):

You can use [MoreLINQ](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/wiki/OperatorsOverview) Batch:

```
var temp3 = temp.Batch(3).Select(b => String.Join(",", b));
```

Comment: Where is that Batch from?

Comment: @JoshuaSon there is a link. You can get MoreLINQ from NuGet

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks a lot for your quick answer. But I'd rather use bare C#. Anyway, thanks a lot again.